# Best way to simplify statement

Tags: php, syntax

I have the following php code.

Im trying to find out the field name/key that does not exist without using hardcoded static text. Is there a php  function that can do this. `array_keys_exist` is similar to what I want but it only allows for checking of a single key.

ex:

Something like

```
$keys_to_confirm = ['password','password_old',....];

$user_submitted_input_array = ['password'=>'...', 'somekey'=>'...' ];

bool : all_array_keys_exist($keys_to_confirm,$user_submitted_input_array);
```

Current code that uses static text to report the missing field/key name

```
    if( isset($input['password']))
    {
        if( isset($input['password_old'])) )
        {
            if(isset($input['password_repeat'])) )
            {
                //good to go!
            }
            else
            {
                die('missing form element password_repeat.');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            die('missing form element password_old.');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        die('missing form element password.');
    }
```

I had this code but it doesnt say what is missing.

```
        //if the field doesnt exist for some reason lets create a dummy
        if( ! isset($input['password']) 
            OR (!isset($input['password_repeat']))
            OR (!isset($input['password_old'])) )
        {
            die('missing form element.');
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could look into `array_diff_key` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php

Comment: @RhapX Yes there is a user function posted there called `same_keys ($a1, $a2)` Looks interesting.. hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach( array('password', 'password_repeat', 'password_old') as $key ) {
  if( empty($input[ $key ]) ) {
    echo 'Missing field: ' . $key;
  }
}
```

You can probably come up with a one liner to do this using array_diff_key, but I think the above is concise enough.

Comment: Thanks for your input, one liners arnt always the solution, I think your solution is easy to read and understand

Answer (score 1):

Here's the one liner with `array_key_diff`. It's not the prettiest but functional.

```
$keys_to_confirm = array('password' => '','password_old' => '');
$user_submitted_input_array = array('password'=>'...', 'somekey'=>'...');

$validate = array_diff_key($keys_to_confirm, $user_submitted_input_array);

if( empty($validate) ) {
    echo 'Passed';
} else {
    echo 'Missing field: ' . key($validate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
if ($field_miss = array_diff_key(array('password', 'password_old', '...'), array_keys($input))) {
    echo 'Missing field: ', implode(', ', $field_miss);
}
```